# How to include <lua.h>?

Tags: c, lua

When you `#include` files with `<>`, the compiler searcher for the headers in a certain location(s). Where am I supposed to keep the lua files for that to work? I guess I know where all(?) of gcc's `.h` files are at. Or do I have to keep them in the same project folder and do `#include "lua.h"` instead? I assume I should use whatever is in LuaDist instead of the binaries, since it's not compiled.

(I'm using Windows if it's needed to know that)

Comment: You need to look at the `-I` option in the [Directory Options](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Directory-Options.html#Directory-Options) for gcc.

Comment: Where were the Lua headers installed? If you're on a Unix-like box, one plausible location is `/usr/local/include` for the headers and somewhere under `/usr/local/lib` for the libraries.  In that case, you'd need to add `-I/usr/local/include` to the compiler command line, and `-L/usr/local/lib` to the linker command line. Some compilers may be configured to use those locations automatically. Another possibility would be that Lua is installed in `/opt/lua`; then you'd add `-I/opt/lua/include` and `-L/opt/lua/lib` to the command lines (and it is unlikely that any compiler uses those locations).

Comment: The way I do it is creating `include` folder in my project, then simply adding `-I ./include` and it will automatically find all header files that are used by project by simply using standard `#include <lua.h>`, this helps separate files that are strictly your project files and others which are dependencies, whether it's STD or 3rd party libraries, both in code and in project folder itself. But this is normally done if you are using plain MinGW (for example), if you use Visual Studio, you should look up how to add include, library and linker options to your project settings.

Comment: In Visual Studio you should add library path to lua library in your project configuration.

Answer (score 6):

*Edit*: This is probably useless for Windows, sorry.  If anyone running Linux/BSD/macOS/Solaris/*etc.* comes across this in the future, though:

There should be a pkg-config file available for Lua which will tell you exactly what flags you need.  For Lua 5.1 (the version I see on Fedora 28), it's `lua-5.1`.  So, to compile:

```
cc … `pkg-config --cflags --libs lua-5.1`
```

Comment: The OP is running Windows.

Comment: Oh, poor soul ☹.  I guess I'll leave the answer up in case Google sends someone this way in the future, but yeah this answer is probably useless for OP.

Comment: Even on linux, you should use `-I` compiler option instead of relying on crutches that might not even exist on some distributions, keep your scripts for yourself, there's a standard way of doing it cross platform as long as you have a C compiler and that's the only answer that should be given out. If you really want to shove it in then you can append "yeah if you use linux you can also do it like this". The least you'd want is people new to programming asking "what's equivalent to linux cc on windows". kthx.